# DynamoDB create tables in local machine

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have downloaded DynamoDB jars to my local windows machine and able to start service using command below.

```
java -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -dbPath .
```

i can access the web console using localhost:8000/shell/

However, I am not sure how to create table, can someone give me the syntax and any examples

if I want to create table with below details, how to do and insert the data?

Table: student
columns: sid, firstname, lastname, address.

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: what language are you using? (python, java..)

Comment: I ran the tutorial by running `tutorial.start()`. It's been really helpful.

Answer (score 30):

The documentation can be a bit difficult to understand. Since you are using the dynamodb shell, I'll assume you are asking for a JavaScript query to create the table.

```js
var params = {
TableName: 'student',
KeySchema: [ 
    { 
        AttributeName: 'sid',
        KeyType: 'HASH',
    },
],
AttributeDefinitions: [ 
    {
        AttributeName: 'sid',
        AttributeType: 'N', 
    },
    
    
],
ProvisionedThroughput: { 
    ReadCapacityUnits: 10, 
    WriteCapacityUnits: 10, 
},
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response

});
```

Run the above snippet in the browser at the local db shell

http://localhost:8000/shell/

It creates a table with 'sid' as hash key.

To insert:

```js
var params = {
    TableName: 'student',
    Item: { // a map of attribute name to AttributeValue
        sid: 123,
        firstname : { 'S': 'abc' },
        lastname : { 'S': 'xyz' },
        address : {'S': 'pqr' },
        ReturnValues: 'NONE', // optional (NONE | ALL_OLD)
        ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'NONE', // optional (NONE | TOTAL | INDEXES)
        ReturnItemCollectionMetrics: 'NONE', // optional (NONE | SIZE)
    }
};
docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

Comment: Been looking at this for several days. This is literally the first time I've seen `localhost:8000/shell` referenced. Says a lot about the state of documentation in the area!

Comment: yeah, took me a day to figure out what was wrong. And this is just one of the many services.

Comment: You can also use https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-table-schema-design-tool/ to generate the `params` as it has quite difficult structure.

Answer (score 27):

I would recommend using docker (but running the jar is also possible):

```sh
$ docker run -d -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local
```

Then you can create a table in the docker container by passing in the `endpoint-url`:

```sh
$ aws dynamodb create-table \
   --table-name UnifiedTable \
   --attribute-definitions AttributeName=pk,AttributeType=S AttributeName=sk,AttributeType=S \
   --key-schema AttributeName=pk,KeyType=HASH AttributeName=sk,KeyType=RANGE \
   --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
   --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

You can check if the table exists like this:

```sh
$ aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000

# Output:
# {
#     "TableNames": [
#         "UnifiedTable"
#     ]
# }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can view the API documentation here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/Welcome.html

Or you can as well use `aws-cli` for your local DynamoDB installation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.CLI.html#Tools.CLI.UsingWithDDBLocal

Comment: The documentation states that I can list-tables for local DB like this `aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000`. How do I create tables locally though? For example the node.js documentation states I can provide an endpoint_url: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.01.html. But aws.config.update no longer supports an endpoint_url.

Answer (score 0):

```
aws.config.update({
 dynamodb: {
      endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000'
 },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try [DynamoDB shell](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-shell) tool, to run **SQL-like commands** on DynamoDB tables.