# Create tables in local AWS dynamoDB besed on information from aws-sam template.yaml file using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sam

I have running local dynamoDB in Java integration tests

```
AmazonDynamoDBLocal embeddedDynamo = DynamoDBEmbedded.create()
AmazonDynamoDB client = embeddedDynamo.amazonDynamoDB();
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
```

Now I need to create tables based on definition in SAM template.yaml file. I can just copy that file on classpath using Gradle and parse it by some Java/Groovy tools and then just use parsed map to feed the DynamoDB instance API to create those tables.

But I am wondering if there is any library or tool that does it for me?

Thank you,
Lukas

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create it yourself. You can do this using a json file and the aws cli's `dynamodb` command, for example:

**my-table.json**

```
{
    "TableName": "MyTable",
    "KeySchema": [
      { "AttributeName": "Id", "KeyType": "HASH" }
    ],
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
      { "AttributeName": "Id", "AttributeType": "S" }
    ],
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
      "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
      "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
    }
}
```

**aws cli's dynamodb create-table command example**

`aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://my-table.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000`

**Notes**

- you can do this without the json file.
- more info in the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/create-table.html

Comment: But you are telling me how to do it using CLI. The question was how to do it using java code. The point is I have integration tests and they need to be able to completly setup the environment and then clean it up in tests runtime. The database is up only over the tests run.  And I also have the dynamoDB setup defined in yaml and same definition needs to be used for both the real deployment and tests. So no separated json

Comment: Ah. I see now. I believe that this answer should be of use to you then.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43385883/794088

Comment: No you don't.. You shared how to use API. But I want literaly say inside the jave code "Take template.yaml, extract the dynamoDB setup from that file and use it to create those tables localy". And I was asking about existing tool. But there is nothing like that I guess so  I will have to create some

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744216/how-do-i-convert-from-yaml-to-json-in-java